# How to fix NSTextView's weird sizing inside a magnified NSScrollView

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstextview, nsscrollview

I have an NSTextView inside NSScrollView/NSClipView, the usual setup. When I magnify the scroll view with `[NSScrollView setMagnification:...]` and resize the window, the width of text view's frame gets constantly larger, regardless of whether I stretch or shrink the window.

If the scroll view is not magnified, text view behaves normally. I have tried removing constraints and disabled subview autoresizing, but nothing helps. Whenever i set any sort of magnification, text view size changes on every call to resize. If the magnification is under 1, it shrinks.

Any bugs in TextContainer shouldn't make it wider either, as I've set `textContainer.widthTracksTextView = false;`

I am trying to keep the textContainer centered in my NSTextView by setting insets to it, but it gets impossible with the varying sizes. I've gone through my code and nothing should make it resize. Is this a bug or does the `setMagnify:` cause problems with constraints or some other math in LayoutManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to figure this out:
This is caused by a minimum width constraint for the magnified view, or any of its subviews. Seems like a bug, as I can't wrap my head around how this would be intended behaviour.

Just remove the `>=` constraint and do something to limit the size in run-time if needed.