# NSTextView in magnified NSScrollView crashes on resize

Tags: macos, nstextview, nsscrollview

This is similar to [How to fix NSTextView's weird sizing inside a magnified NSScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56005593/how-to-fix-nstextviews-weird-sizing-inside-a-magnified-nsscrollview), but I seem to have a slightly different problem, and the suggested solution does not work for me.

Basically, I have an NSTextView inside an NSScrollView with magnification. Zooming in with a pinch-and-zoom gesture and then resizing the window causes a crash with the error `The window has been marked as needing another Display Window pass, but it has already had more Display Window passes than there are views in the window.`

I have made a video illustrating the problem here: https://youtu.be/M_JRQI2oDaY

The project is here: https://github.com/angstsmurf/spatterlight/tree/helpviewtest

(The branch helpviewtest is a cut down test case created for this problem.)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Nope, I gave up. I have a hunch there is a subview with an intrinsic size or a conflicting layout constraint somewhere in there.

Comment: I found out for me it was related to changing the `ruleThickness` within a `NSRulerView`'s function `override func drawHashMarksAndLabels(in rect: NSRect)`.